# Why is this conditional MySQL update/set not working?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sql-update

I have the below query executed via PDO prepare then execute in PHP.

I want the value of `managerCommentsId` to change only if `managerComments` has changed.

The assignment of `managerComments` works as expected, but `managerCommentsId` never updates no matter what value is passed, but there are no errors. If I change the line to simply `managerCommentsId = :uid` it works as expected (but obviously loses the desired conditional). As far as I can tell from other posts this syntax is correct, so what am I missing?

```
UPDATE `bookings`
    SET `status` = :status,
        `managerComments` = IF(`managerComments` != :managerComments, :managerComments, `managerComments`),
        `managerCommentsId` = IF(`managerComments` != :managerComments, :uid, `managerCommentsId`),
        `editedBy` = :uid
    WHERE `id` = :id
      AND `organisationId` = :organisationId
```

SQL 5.6, InnoDB, MySQL

Comment: Can you try swapping the two lines over(the update of the comments after the id) see if the order makes a difference.

Comment: As far as I know each placeholder, or parameter marker, has to be unique, so use `:managerComments1` and `:managerComments2` etc.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware it is i the query I'm running, I took out the numbers in the above example for clarity

Comment: @NigelRen interestingly this swaps the problem - so now `managerCommentsId` is working but `managerComments` is not. Is this something to do with only being able to compare `managerComments` once?

Comment: by the way, the condition for managerComments is totally useless

Comment: See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @YourCommonSense you're right, not sure why I included that. This does solve the problem but if anyone knows why the original didn't work I'd lvoe to know (as far as I can tell the `managerComments` condition is redundant but shouldn't prevent the other checks"

Comment: the main problem here is the wrong database structure. if you want a change history then you need a full featured change history table

Comment: 'Is this something to do with only being able to compare managerComments once? ' -not quite set statements take effect immediately so by your second test managerComments = :managerComments - you could test this by setting managerComments to itself in the first test and check if managerCommentsId is updated. –

Answer (score 0):

Swapped the order of operations as suggested by @NigelRen which updated `managerCommentsId` but not `managerComments` (problem reversed). Then @YourCommonSense pointed out the conditional on `managerComments` was pointless so remvoed it and all working now.

```
UPDATE `bookings`
SET `status` = :status,
    `managerCommentsId` = IF((`bookings`.`managerComments` != :managerComments1) OR
                             (`bookings`.`managerComments` IS NULL AND :managerComments2 IS NOT NULL) OR
                             (`bookings`.`managerComments` IS NOT NULL AND :managerComments3 IS NULL), :uid1,
                             `bookings`.`managerCommentsId`),
    `managerComments` = :managerComments4,
    `editedBy` = :uid2
WHERE `id` = :id
  AND `organisationId` = :organisationId
```